# Insufficient Number of Instruments Error PLM IV on Unbalanced Panel

Tags: r, panel, instruments, plm, ivreg

I am attempting to run the following IV regression on an unbalanced panel dataset. The variables TOTAL_E, TOURISM_5k_SUM and TOURISM_10K_SUM are endogenous, while HHSIZE2 and SEX are exogenous explanatory variables, and Z_b_100,tourism_5KM_ZSCORE and tourism_10KM_ZSCORE are instruments. I want to include household characteristics as controls in this regression. I do so and am also sure to include them in the formula with the IVs, but every time I still get the insufficient number of instruments error. I am using a random effects model since my instrument is time invariant so I don't believe that is the issue.

Based on this question:[Error "insufficient number of instruments" when running plm IV regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672684/error-insufficient-number-of-instruments-when-running-plm-iv-regression), I am supposed to have 2 instruments for every endogenous variable but that isn't possible in my case so I am a bit stuck.

```
random <- plm(asinh(AECAPITA)~asinh(TOTAL_E) +asinh(TOURISM_5KM_SUM)+asinh(TOURISM_10KM_SUM) + HHSIZE2 + SEX|Z_b_100 + HHSIZE2 + tourism_5KM_ZSCORE + tourism_10KM_ZSCORE+ SEX ,data=df,index=c("UNIQUE_HH_ID","YEAR"), model="random")


Error in plm.fit(data, model = models[1L], effect = effect) : 
  insufficient number of instruments
In addition: Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first turn to the warning as this hints your data set is not correctly specified ("duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame"). There are numerous questions and answers about this on SO, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092725/4640346. Basically, you need to have unique pairs of the dimension of the observational unit and the time dimension. The warning also contains a hint how to check for this.

I suggest to first create the `pdata.frame` and then input it in `plm()` without the `index` argument. This way, you will know if you specified the data set correctly first (it somewhat corresponds to Stata's `xtset`).

When the data is correctly specified, try to re-estimate the model with it and see if you still get the error.

Overall approach would be something along these lines:

```
pdf <- pdata.frame(df, index=c("UNIQUE_HH_ID","YEAR"))
mod <- plm(formula, data = pdf, <further_specs>)
```